# how to update model object's , only one field data when doing serializer.save() in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

so heres my serializer class:

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Hero
        fields=['id','name','secret_identity']
```

and my view :

```
@api_view(['PUT', ])
def api_hero_update(request, name):
    try:
        character = Hero.objects.get(name=name)
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    serializer = serializers.HeroSerializer(character, data=request.data)
    message={}
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        print(serializer.data)
        message["success"]="Update Successful"
        return Response(data=message)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Let a model object has fields name and secret_identity. and i want to update its name only but the line

```
serializer = serializers.HeroSerializer(character, data=request.data)
```

doesnt allow me to update only , one field . how to update only one field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add `partial=True` attribute to serializer object. i.e. use this

```
serializer = serializers.HeroSerializer(character, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

By overriding the serializers `update` method:

```py
class HeroSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Hero
        fields=['id','name','secret_identity']


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.secret_identity = validated_data.get('your field name', 'defaultvalue')
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Don't forget to save your model inside the `update` method, or the changes wont be persistent in the database. If you need more information, this is described in the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).